# syntaxerror in code but not in line of code

Tags: python, syntax-error

So I'm trying to program something and there's something odd going on, when trying to run my code I get a syntaxerror on line 3 but when I run only that specific line of code everything works perfectly. How is this even possible? It's written in python if that matters

```
p = float(input("What is the initial investment?   "))
r = float(input("What is the nominal interest rate as a decimal?   ")
n = float(input("How many times a year will the interest be compounded?      "))
t = float(input("How many years will the interest be compounded"))

a = p * (1 + r / n) ** (n*t)

print "The final amount after %f years is %f" %t %a
```

Comment: The problem is in your second line. Close the brackets.

Comment: The actual syntax error is on line number 2

Answer (score 2):

Try this, (missed `brackets` in `2nd` line).

```
r = float(input("What is the nominal interest rate as a decimal?   "))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing bracket on line 2. Correct that, and the error should go away.

```
#Instead of
r = float(input("What is the nominal interest rate as a decimal?   ")
#Do this
r = float(input("What is the nominal interest rate as a decimal?   "))
#This guy is missing - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ^
```